# Quantitative trading strategies with a focus on low-frequency dislocations

Tags: options, futures, quant-trading-strategies, reference-request

I am looking for references that are specific to quantitative trading strategies that exploit low-frequency dislocations in markets, which lend themselves as overlays for a strategic asset allocation of a multi-asset portfolio (equities, high-yield credit, bonds, precious metals) that improve the overall portfolio performance statistics. Instruments used could be quite flexible, for example futures, options or CDS.

One reference that I already found is [Advanced Futures Trading Strategies](https://www.harriman-house.com/advancedfuturestradingstrat) by Robert Carver, but only a few strategies covered would come close to the description above.

Comment: Pls consider focusing your question on a more specific issue because, as it is, it is likely to lead to low quality link-only answers.